# Can other nodes in system see the state of my contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, nodes, privacy

I created a simple contract which has a simple state with a single int.

[image]

I gave it a value of 90 at the deployment time (constructor).

Now I went to the particular block in Rinkeby, and I could see the Bytecode of my contract code.

But I am not sure if other nodes can see that I had set the value to 90.

Or one can see it only if there is a getter for it?

I am sorry if my question is very basic. I have just got stared with Ethereum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to @Andrey's answer, your contract makes it inconvenient to access the data. If it is your intention to make that easily accessible by other contracts and observers, you can make the visibility `public` with

`uint public value`

That will give everyone a helpful function that is functionally equivalent to:

`function value() public view returns(uint) {
  return value;
}`

When you don't do that, it's harder for observers, but ...

All data is available to all full nodes who are independently validating transactions sent to your contract. They all independently conclude `90`. Implicitly, anyone with the know-how to work at the miner/node software level or how to rumage around in raw storage in Solidity can find their way to that number.

Also, the data payload for the transaction that set the value to `90` is forever visible to everyone via a block explorer. Everyone can see `90` on its way to the setter functions.

Main takeaway? It's very tricky to keep a secret on the blockchain. `private` may be sort of misleading.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

All blockchain data is public. Since your contract(and its state) is stored in the blockchain, variables are also public.